# Can I insert null for a decimal column that allows null

Tags: f#-data, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I have this SqlCommandProvider:

```
type Insert_NewFeed =
    SqlCommandProvider<
                        "
                            INSERT INTO info.LiveFeed
                                    ( Id ,
                                        MediaId ,
                                        FactTypeId ,
                                        Price ,
                                        Description ,
                                        PhoneNumber ,
                                        Email ,
                                        Website ,
                                        CreateDate ,
                                        CityId
                                    )
                            VALUES  ( @id , -- Id - nvarchar(128)
                                        @mediaId , -- MediaId - nvarchar(128)
                                        @factTypeId , -- FactTypeId - int
                                        @price , -- Price - decimal
                                        @description , -- Description - nvarchar(max)
                                        @phoneNumber , -- PhoneNumber - nvarchar(50)
                                        @email , -- Email - nvarchar(max)
                                        @website , -- Website - nvarchar(max)
                                        @createDate , -- CreateDate - datetime2
                                        @cityId  -- CityId - int
                                    )
                        ", Admin.connectionString, ConfigFile = "Web.config">
```

When I call it and try to pass null for the price column, which accepts a null in the database, I get an error. Is this possible?

Table definition:

```
[Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[MediaId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[FactTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Website] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[CityId] [int] NULL
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing table definition

Comment: I've added the table definition for you.

Comment: I see, yes, inference doesn't work for this case. You can have desired behavior with ``AllParametersOptional`` as described in [Optional input parameters](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/configuration%20and%20input.html)

Comment: Another nice option is to use DataTable, here is a couple of tests: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/blob/master/src/SqlClient.Tests/DataTablesTests.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dimitry Sevastianov's comment, here is the solution.

First, assigned true to the parameter AllParametersOptional:

```
type Insert_NewFeed =
SqlCommandProvider<
                    "
                        INSERT INTO info.LiveFeed
                                ( Id ,
                                    MediaId ,
                                    FactTypeId ,
                                    Price ,
                                    Description ,
                                    PhoneNumber ,
                                    Email ,
                                    Website ,
                                    CreateDate ,
                                    CityId
                                )
                        VALUES  ( @id , -- Id - nvarchar(128)
                                    @mediaId , -- MediaId - nvarchar(128)
                                    @factTypeId , -- FactTypeId - int
                                    @price , -- Price - decimal
                                    @description , -- Description - nvarchar(max)
                                    @phoneNumber , -- PhoneNumber - nvarchar(50)
                                    @email , -- Email - nvarchar(max)
                                    @website , -- Website - nvarchar(max)
                                    @createDate , -- CreateDate - datetime2
                                    @cityId  -- CityId - int
                                )
                    ", Admin.connectionString, ConfigFile = "Web.config"
                     , AllParametersOptional = true>
```

Next, make call such as this:

```
let rowResult = (new Insert_NewFeed())
                                .Execute(Some fC.Id, Some fC.MediaId, Some fC.FactTyeId, 
                                    None,
                                    Some fC.Description, Some fC.PhoneNumber, Some fC.Email,
                                    Some fC.Website, Some fC.CreateDate, Some fC.CityId)
```